# Cannot authenticate on Apache Cassandra 2.2.x

Tags: java, spring-data-cassandra

Trying to accomplish a simple proof of concept using Spring Data Gosling (RELEASE) and Spring Data Cassandra (1.3.0.RELEASE, imported from the parent BOM). The configuration class I use is the following:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/cassandra/cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "com.test.repositories" })
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean(); 
        cluster.setUsername(environment.getProperty("cassandra.username"));
        cluster.setPassword(environment.getProperty("cassandra.password"));
        cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
        return cluster;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

}
```

Starting the program leads to an error regarding authentication:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /127.0.0.1:9042: Host /127.0.0.1:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.objectway.dwx.datatest.main.Application.main(Application.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /127.0.0.1:9042: Host /127.0.0.1:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /127.0.0.1:9042: Host /127.0.0.1:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:294)
    at com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79ffe213.session(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration.cassandraTemplate(AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java:85)
    at com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79ffe213.CGLIB$cassandraTemplate$7(<generated>)
    at com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79ffe213$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f6ee548e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at com.objectway.dwx.datatest.config.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79ffe213.cassandraTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /127.0.0.1:9042: Host /127.0.0.1:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AuthProvider$1.newAuthenticator(AuthProvider.java:39)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:259)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$5.apply(Connection.java:246)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:863)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Future.onSet(Connection.java:1183)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1013)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:936)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:847)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Using **AllowAllAuthentication** on the Cassandra side works flawlessly. The problem appears when I use **PasswordAuthentication**. On Cassandra 2.2.x,
dependency analysis shows the whole package is depending on the Datastax cassandra-driver-dse version 2.1.8 (which, on the other side, depends on the cassandra-driver-core 2.1.8). Forcing the driver dependency to the actual 2.2.0-rc3 leads to other problems, probably because it's still in an unsupported state.

Should I give up using data-cassandra with C* 2.2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out spring-data-cassandra 1.3.0.RELEASE CAN authenticate towards Apache Cassandra 2.2.x
All you need is building an AuthProvider object. The DataStax driver provides a concrete implementation for this interface: PlainTextAuthProvider.
The final cluster() method should be created like this:

```
@Bean
@Override
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean(); 
    PlainTextAuthProvider sap = new PlainTextAuthProvider(env.getProperty("cassandra.username"), env.getProperty("cassandra.password"));
    cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
    cluster.setAuthProvider(sap);
    return cluster;
}
```